# Decode 32bit float with decade exponent

Tags: python

I have this definition of a binary data (received from ModBus):

```
Signed Measurement (32 bit):
  Decade Exponent (Signed 8 bit)
  Binary Signed value (24 bit)
Example: - 123456*10-3 = FDFE 1DC0(16)
```

I was trying to use `struct.unpack` to get the actual float from the binary data, but it yields wrong value (probably correct in terms of the documentation, because NodeJS also yields the same value).

```py
In [92]: result = b'\xfd\x01\xe2\x40'

In [93]: struct.unpack(">f", result)
Out[93]: (-1.0790323038781103e+37,)
```

I've managed to get it in two goes:

```py
In [86]: result = b'\xfd\x01\xe2\x40'

In [87]: decade_exponent = struct.unpack(">b", result[0:1])[0]

In [88]: decade_exponent
Out[88]: -3

In [89]: binary_value = int.from_bytes(result[1:], 'big')

In [90]: binary_value
Out[90]: 123456

In [91]: binary_value * 10 ** decade_exponent
Out[91]: 123.456
```

But I was thinking if there is a simpler way to do it?

Comment: This is not a standard format for floating-point numbers; there isn't going to be any significantly easier way to decode them.

Comment: @jasonharper, thanks. That's useful. I thought that maybe it's some kind of a standard.

Comment: One thing to make it easier though: `decade_exponent = int.from_bytes(result[0:1], 'big', signed=True)`